# 'MID' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, powerbuilder

I am trying to run the following :

```
SELECT auth.c_name,            
    auth.auth, 
    MID( auth.auth, 1 ,1) AS COLUMN_0,
    ( select "function" from key5932 where "key-index" =0 ) as index0,
```

But i am getting following error:   'MID' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Is this Powerbuilder connecting to an Access database? Have you tried the same SQL query in Access directly?

Comment: Please elaborate, your question is too short. What version are you using exactly? What do you want to achieve and in what context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use SUBSTR OR SUBSTRING I forgot it. mid is function properly if java is enabled in ASE.

Happy coding

Comment: Mid is a valid method in Access

Comment: hard to keep track of all the language subtleties, no wonder I feel like I'm getting null pointers in my brain already.